# How to Authenticate Enterprise GitHub with VS Code by manually keying in enterprise Github link and personal token

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

We recently installed VS Code and have been trying to integrate our enterprise GitHub repo.
Please find below output log. We have updated setting with enterprise GitHub Uri.

Trying to figure out how can we manually add personal token and get GitHub authenticated.

VS Code Output Log -

```
2023-02-13 19:36:16.646 [info] info: detecting host provider for 'https://egithub.XXXXXXX.com/'...
remote: Password authentication is not available for Git operations.
remote: You must use a personal access token or SSH key.
remote: See https://egithub.XXXXXXX.com/settings/tokens or https://egithub.XXXXXX.com/settings/ssh
fatal: unable to access 'https://eagithub.XXXXXXX.com/123456/XYZSYS_Demo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Tried installing and reloading VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Try first in command line to check if you are correctly authenticated, using for testing [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)

```
git ls-remote https://egithub.XXXXXXX.com/you/aPrivateRepository
```

If you still get 403 even in command-line, check your Git credential helper, which might have cached the wrong credential (a GitHub account password, instead of a GitHub [personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic) with [scope `repo`](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes))

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

If it is "`manager`":

```
printf "host=egithub.XXXXXXX.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=you" | git credential-manager get
```

(replace "you" by your GitHub user account name).

Only once it is working in command-line can you switch back to VSCode.